# Why `kitchen` instead of `cooking room`?

Tags: etymology

Most room names contain `room`, like

- bedroom
- bathroom
- living room
- dinning room
- sunroom

Why `kitchen` instead of `cooking room`? :p

Comment: We also say **lounge**, **hall**, **study**, **attic** etc. The etymology of English words isn't consistent.

Comment: A kitchen is a room or part of a room used for cooking and food preparation in a dwelling or in a commercial establishment. The name is derived from the french translation of 'Cooking Room'. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchen

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitchen) says "Middle English *kichene*, from Old English *cycene*, from Late Latin *coquina*, from Latin *coquere* to cook."

Comment: Nice, thank you for this additional information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure where the idea came from that ***kitchen*** is French for "cooking room". That would be *salle de cuisine*, or possibly *salle à cuisiner* - neither of which I have ever heard used. The French for "kitchen" is *cuisine*, which is the same word that means "cooking" (n), and *cuire* and *cuisiner* are verbs "to cook".

The word "kitchen" has both Latin and Germanic roots as the following extract from the OED indicates:

> Etymology: Old English cycene weak feminine = Old Low German *kukina
>   (Middle Dutch coken(e , koekene , kuekene , Dutch keuken ; Middle Low
>   German kokene , Low German köke(n , kök ; hence Danish kökken , also
>   dialect köken , Swedish kök ), Old High German chuhhîna (Middle High
>   German küche(n , kuche(n , German küche , and obsolete or dialect küch
>   , kuch(e) < vulgar Latin cucīna , cocīna , variant of coquīna , <
>   coquĕre to cook v.1 Of the Middle English forms, those in y, i were
>   originally midland and northern; those in u southern and especially
>   s.w., with ü = Old English y; those in e partly Kentish with e for Old
>   English y, partly northern and midl. with e widened < i.

Comment: Nitpicking: the word doesn’t have Germanic roots as such. It’s a Latin word which was borrowed into an early stage of West Germanic, whence it developed more or less regularly into the modern form. So its _roots_ are Latin, but it’s gone through various later developments once it entered West Germanic and later on English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. I think I did realise that, but I'm afraid my knowledge of the history of Indo-European language does not extend nearly far enough to pick out German and Latin etymologies.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's like saying that leafy *rocket* (aka *arugula*) has both French and Italian roots because the original Italian word took a long holiday in France en route to England. :)

Answer (score 2):

**kitchen**  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=kitchen)

> "**room in which food is cooked, part of a building fitted out for
>   cooking," c. 1200**, from Old English cycene "kitchen," from
>   Proto-Germanic *kokina (source also of Middle Dutch cökene, Old High
>   German chuhhina, German Küche, Danish kjøkken), probably borrowed from
>   Vulgar Latin *cocina (source also of French cuisine, Spanish cocina),
>   a variant of Latin coquina "kitchen," from fem. of coquinus "of
>   cooks," from coquus "cook," from coquere "to cook."

Answer (score 2):

Actually, *cook rooms* are (were?) a thing. The Oxford English Dictionary dates the expression to [1553](http://www.searchengine.org.uk/pdfs/2/987.pdf), meaning *galley*:

> The cooke roome, and all other places to be kept cleane.

*Kitchen* is a much older word, dating back to [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cycene). And the five “-room” words listed in the question are from later, with the earliest one showing up about 1600.

(A good question would be why were these “-room” words coined when we already had perfectly good words like “bedchamber”.  But language is like that a lot, just not with kitchen being replaced by something ending in “-room”.)